# How to modify or update laravel's Implicit controller to get desired url?

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5, implicit

I am using `Route:Controller` for a laravel 5.2 project.

I found myself in an interesting situation.

Suppose My route file has this code

```
Route::controller('test','TestController');
```

`TestController` has following methods

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        dd('index');
    }
    public function getDetails($id){
     return $id.'/details';
    }
    public function getItem($var1,$var2){
     return $var1.$var2.'/item';
    }


}
```

so if i route `localhost:8000/test`  it shows the content of `getIndex()` method.

Now i want to browse **url** for this **item's details**

```
localhost::8000/test/item1/details
localhost::8000/test/item2/details
localhost::8000/test/item3/details
....
localhost::8000/test/itemN/details
```

I don't know how to do it when my route controller is like this

```
Route::controller('test','TestController');
```

Because all **items** are **variables** . So to get my desired result i changed my route like this:

```
Route::controller('test/{id}','TestController');
```

and now i can access these url

```
localhost::8000/test/item3/details
```

But problem is now i am unable to access `localhost::8000/test`

I also wanted to access following  url too

```
localhost::8000/test/item3/shop1/details
localhost::8000/test/item3/shop2/details
```

So how can i solve this problem without using `route::resource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to overcome this challenge.

In my route file i add two new routes

```
Route::get('test/{var1}/{var2}/details','TestController@getItem');
Route::get('test/{id}/details','TestController@getDetails');
```

Now i can access these urls

```
localhost::8000/test
localhost::8000/test/item3/details
localhost::8000/test/item3/shop1/details
```

But found a problem. Which is , i can also access the data using following urls

```
localhost::8000/test/details/item3
localhost::8000/test/details/item3/shop1
```

So to prevent this i have change my method

```
public function getDetails($id){
     return $id.'/details';
    }
    public function getItem($var1,$var2){
     return $var1.$var2.'/item';
    }
```

to

```
public function details($id){
     return $id.'/details';
    }
    public function item($var1,$var2){
     return $var1.$var2.'/item';
    }
```

and routes modified as

```
Route::get('test/{var1}/{var2}/details','TestController@getItem');
Route::get('test/{id}/details','TestController@getDetails');
```

to

```
Route::get('test/{var1}/{var2}/details','TestController@item');
Route::get('test/{id}/details','TestController@details');
```

Looking for better way to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have so much knowledge but i think it will do something..

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'test'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){return "hi";});
    Route::get('/{id}', function($id){return "hi".$id;});
    Route::get('/{id}/{id2}', function($id, $id2){return "hi".$id.$id2;});
});
```

Comment: Tnx for your effort but i have many methods within TestController and implicit   controller does append test before every url. So if i have a method name getInformation in TestController , it will generate this url test/information and  i don't want to write all these route manually .

Comment: so why not using route like this - localhost/test/detail/itemid/shopid?
or you are sticking with your given url?

Comment: For SEO purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit Controllers** for routing support is dropped from L5.2. You can use RESTFul Controllers instead to decrease your route declaration.

Comment: i am using Laravel Framework version 5.2.24 and it works fine :)

Comment: It's deprecated and as soon as version 5.3 will land it will be dropped.